# displaying ssn using mask

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I am using mask input pluggin for displaying ssn.I am getting the ssn value from database.All the ssn should be masked with * only last four digits should be displayed. Example `***-***-1234.`
 can someone help me?

Comment: it should diplay as *****-1234. i was thinking of using mask

Comment: format data from the server itself

Comment: @ArunKillu i am suppose to do it the front end

Comment: the original purpose of hiding the ssn will not be accomplished if you do like that

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to do this in jQuery - you want to do it in your backend  .. else it will be visible to the end user - for example if they have JavaScript enabled.

Doing this in the backend means that the data sent to the browser doesnt contain this information, for an example (and i have no idea what backend language / database your using) you could create a query :

```
select SUBSTRING(ssn, -4) from table
```

this will get just the last 4 characters from the field `ssn` ... and then add the `*`'s on the page using HTML

Comment: @user1234 insecure/unreliable ... what happens if the browser has javascript disabled ?

Comment: how does this solve the issue for an input field? this seems a solution for static content only, what happens when the user changes it/types something in for the first time?